# When does a parameterized curve lie within a given vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector-valued curve parameterized by a single parameter $\alpha$ such that:

$$ \vec{x} = \sum_{i=1}^nf_i(\alpha)\vec{e_i}$$

where $\vec{e_i}$ is the $i^{th}$ standard Euclidean basis vector (that is, it's 0 for all of its components except i, where it is 1).  All of the $f_i$ are actually known and come from the quadratic equation:

$$f_i = \frac{-\alpha k_i \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 - k_i^2 + 1}}{\alpha^2 + 1}$$

where $k_i\in \mathbb{R}$ is a known constant that is different for each $f_i$.  Note that, due to the $\pm$ in the definition, I actually have $2^n$ possible curves that I'm interested in.  For the remainder of the discussion, let us assume that I'm interested in determining my solution for an *arbitrary choice* of curve within the family $F$.

In addition to this, I have another vector $\vec{w}$ that is known.  This vector imposes a constraint on $\vec{x}$ that $\vec{x}\cdot \vec{w} = 0$, so $\vec{x}$ must lie within $\vec{w}$'s orthogonal complement.

I have three questions:

1) For a particular curve arbitrarily chosen from $F$, is there any way of finding out when it can be expressed entirely as a linear combination of basis vectors of $\vec{w}$'s orthogonal complement?

2) Is it possible to solve this for the entire family of curves $F$ at once, or do I have to solve for each of them?  $n$ is typically small enough to make it computationally simple to solve individually, but a general solution would be nicer

3) Is there a nice, general method to do this for any curve?

Comment: It might be easier to solve this problem if we back up and you tell us where the definitions of the $f_i$ came from. Is there a more general definition of $\bf x(\alpha)$?

Comment: I don't think so, but for what it's worth, $\vec{x}$ is defined through three relationships:

1) $\vec{x}\cdot \vec{w} = 0$

2) $\vec{y} \cdot \vec{w} = C, C \in \mathbb{R}$ where the components of $\vec{y}$ are given in terms of those of $\vec{x}$ as: $y_i = \sqrt{1-x_i^2}$

3) the $k_i$ are given as $k_i = \frac{Cw_i}{||\vec{w}||^2}$

From relationships (1) and (2), we have that $\vec{y} = \frac{C\vec{w}}{||\vec{w}||^2} + \alpha\vec{x}$.  Realistically, I want both $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$.

Comment: I should mention that the real issue I've been having is choosing $\vec{x}$ (or $\vec{y}$) so that the two hyperplane equations (relationships 1 and 2) are satisfied while *simultaneously* satisfying the square-root relationship between the $x_i$ and $y_i$.  I've chosen to parameterize $\vec{y}$ as above, solved for $x_i$ in terms of $\alpha$ by substituting it into the parameterization for $y$ using the square root relationship, and see what I get.  That's where the functions came from

Comment: The existence of a $\vec{w}$ such that $\vec{x}\cdot \vec{w} = 0$ means that the curve lies in a $n-1$-dimensional space. But, if I take random $k_i$s, I dont see how it is possible...

Comment: In the second condition you have $x_i^2+y_i^2=1$, they make (parto of) a circle in $(x_i,y_i)$ space. Have you tried making $x_i = \cos \phi_i$ and $y_i = \sin \phi_i$ instead?

Comment: @FlybyNight: that's actually where it all came from in the first place was a set of trigonometric equations. These vectors are actually the last two  need to solve for, but there are 4 more equations that benefitted from the transformation $x_i = cos\theta_i$ etc.  I guess it's possible that these last two equations won't share that benefit.

to: JeanMarie: an existence proof for the solution, or better, a set of bounds on $k_i$ so that a solution exists, would be great as well.  I have some control over $k_i$ from the above mentioned other equations

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky This is what I meant when I asked us to back up. If you could present the original problem there might be a more elegant way of solving it.

Comment: The original equations are a bit much to write out here, but they come from this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory#Coordinate_transformation_of_screws  I have a set of forces and torques acting on the center of mass of a body.  These are applied at contact points, which are oriented in space through a rotation matrix and which reside at points wrt. a central origin.  I want to solve for the orientations and positions for which no net forces/torques act on the body.  Sorry if that's a bit vague, I will try to write out the exact equations when I have a bit more time

Comment: Although I should still mention that I'm interested in the original problem for itself: is it possible to know when a parameterized curve lies within a given vector space?